# Batch If statement not executing properly

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

The issue I'm having is that regardless if whether the if statement is true or not it seems to inconsistently execute. Below is a small example code I made to show you what my problem is, if any one wants to see my actual code it's longer but I can add it as well per request.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set dlspeed=0
set csczer=3

echo %dlspeed% %csczer%

:loop
if "%csczer%" geq "15" (
    TIMEOUT 1
    echo *BOOP*
    TIMEOUT 2
    echo shutdown -h
) 
if "%dlspeed%" lss "1" (
    TIMEOUT 1
    set /a csczer+=1
    goto loop

)

if "%dlspeed%" geq "1" (
    TIMEOUT 1
    set /a csczer=0
    goto loop
) 

@EndLocal
```

And here is the first few lines of output in command prompt:

```
0 3

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
*BOOP*

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
shutdown -h

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
*BOOP*
```

I do not understand why it's immediately going to the if statement that requires csczer to be greater than or equal to 15 when it's clearly equal to 3. I assume it involves that if statement coming first but I don't know why it executes. Thank you in advance for any who attempt to help me, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes so that you are doing an arithmetic comparison instead of a string comparison. No need to enable delayed expansion in the code you have shown, but that does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the surrounding doublequotes from the comparison expressions:

```
if %csczer% geq 15
```

This way a true numeric comparison is performed (as long as you provide numeric values).
With quotes it is a string comparison, for which the character codes are compared, so `3` is considered greater than `15` as the character code of `3` is greater than the code of `1`.

**Note:**
When performing numeric comparisons, avoid leading zeros for the expressions as such are interpreted as *octal* numbers rather than decimal ones, which may lead to unexpected results.

---

Here is the optimised code:

```
@echo off

set dlspeed=0
set csczer=3

echo %dlspeed% %csczer%

:loop
if %csczer% geq 15 (
    TIMEOUT 1
    echo *BOOP*
    TIMEOUT 2
    echo shutdown -h
)
if %dlspeed% lss 1 (
    TIMEOUT 1
    set /a csczer+=1
    goto loop
) else (
    TIMEOUT 1
    set /a csczer=0
    goto loop
)
```

Besides deletion of the unnecessary quotes, I removed `setlocal`/`endlocal` as delayed expansion is not required for this code snippet.
In addition, I improved the logic for checking the value of `dlspeed`.